Python tkinter works in spyder but missing attribute (simpledialog) in shell
I created a simple python script to open a simple dialog box. It works in spyder but not when I run the commands in the shell.
I'm running Linux Mint. I installed Spyder with Anaconda's miniconda.
Here's my code:
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import tkinter as tk
tkwin = tk.Tk()
tkwin.withdraw()
mytext = tk.simpledialog.askstring("A Simple Dialog Box", "Enter some text:", parent=tkwin)

In Spyder, I get the dialog box. When running in the shell, I run python and enter the same Python commands, but I get an error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'simpledialog'

I confirmed that I'm running the same Python in Spyder and script.
Interestingly, print(dir(tk)) in spyder shows simpledialog, but print(dir(tk)) in the shell does not. If I type tk in Spyder's Console, I get
<module 'tkinter' from '/home/keith/Apps/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/tkinter/__init__.py'>

In the shell I get the same thing. What's going on and how do I fix it?
Thanks,
Keith

You are missing  tkinter.simpledialog module.
Snippet:
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.simpledialog #<== Add to module
tkwin = tk.Tk()
tkwin.withdraw()
mytext = tk.simpledialog.askstring("A Simple Dialog Box", "Enter some text:", parent=tkwin)


That worked. Thanks. But... why doesn't prefixing simpledialog with tk allow access to simpledialog? Why does it work in Spyder but not the shell? Maybe the same question: why does dir(tk) have a different result in Spyder vs shell? And while we're at it (sorry), why does importing tkinter.simpledialog allow access to askstring, but importing tkinter doesn't allow access to simpledialog?

You need to update Spyder version.
